# undefined index when calculating distance

Tags: php, google-maps

I am trying to get distance between two places based on latitude and longitude values, but I am getting undefined index error.

```
    <?php  function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2)
    {
    $distance="";
    $duration="";
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
    $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];

    return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
}
//echo GetDrivingDistance(17.4999219, 78.47664, 17.4484114, 78.3631118) . " Kilometers<br>";

$dist = GetDrivingDistance(17.4999219, 78.47664, 17.4484114, 78.3631118);
    echo 'Distance: <b>'.$dist['distance'].'</b><br>Travel time duration: <b>'.$dist['time'].'</b>';
?>
```

Comment: Dump the `$response_a` variable and you shall see the error. With the above code (coords) there's "ZERO_RESULTS" returned.

Comment: I believe that you need to include your application key and you have to enable the app in the apps console on google

Answer (score 1):

From your code,
I have got normally result if I change the lat & long like this.

```
$result = GetDrivingDistance(37.691082,40.520775, -99.807927, -106.971013);
print_r($result);
echo "Distance ".$result['distance'];
```

Output first line with print_r();

```
Array ( [distance] => 913 km [time] => 8 godz. 56 min )
```

And second line with echo

```
913 km
```

Your problem may be about google cannot find the path evaluation from your lat & long

Answer (score 0):

The Lat and log was out of order in the function input. and I added some checks to ensure the output was valid from google which was why you were getting the index notices.  I updated the code to return false if an error occurred when pulling from google.

```
<?php
function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $long1, $lat2, $long2)
{
    $distance="";
    $duration="";
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response, true);

    // check the results
    if($response_a['status'] != 'OK' ||  $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['status'] == "NOT_FOUND") {
        return false;
    }

    $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];

    return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
} 
//echo GetDrivingDistance(17.4999219, 78.47664, 17.4484114, 78.3631118) . " Kilometers";

$dist = GetDrivingDistance(17.4999219, 78.47664, 17.4484114, 78.3631118); 
if($dist) {
    echo 'Distance: '.$dist['distance'].'
    Travel time duration: '.$dist['time'].''; 
} else {
    echo "error";
}

?>
```